# Display images from FTP URL in formula does not work in lightning !!

Tags: lightning, ftp

I am trying to display an image in a formula, this time i am using an FTP URL, it works great in classic but it does not in lightning.

the formula content:

```
IF( ISBLANK( URLPerspective__c ), "", IMAGE( URLPerspective__c , "Perspective" , 180, 360))
```

The FTP URL is stored in the custom Field URLPerspective__c and used in the formula as depicted above.

Example of a ftp URL:

```
ftp://ftp********.jpg
```

Do you have an idea how to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is ever going to work for you. By using FTP, you're essentially downloading content from an insecure link. This will violate Salesforce's security policies.

Comment: Yes, but it works in classic !!

Comment: As with many things that have worked in Classic, there is much that isn't supported in Lightning. Security is being tightened everywhere on the platform. If this were an app from an ISV, it would not pass a security review.